# php preg_match two examples

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to preg_match for

```
src="http://      "
```

where the blank space following // is the rest of the url ending with the ". My adapted doesn't seem to work:

```
preg_match('#src="(http://[^"]+)#', $data, $match);
```

And I am also struggling to get text that starts with > and ends with EITHER a full stop . or an exclamation mark ! or a question mark ? I have no idea how to do this one. An example of the text I want to preg_match for is:

```
 blahblahblah&gt;Hello world this is what I want.
```

I'm hoping a kind preg_match guru can tell me the answer and save me hours of headscratching.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the URL:

```
preg_match('#src="(.*?)"#', $data, $match);
```

and for the second case, use `/>(.*?)(\.|!|\?)/`

Comment: Good solution, but XPath would solve this WITHOUT ANY preg_match ;)

Comment: Thanks Igor. I added a # into the first one to make it work and the second works great too. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

(.*?)" will match any character greedily up until the time it sees the end double quote

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to parse a document or string which follows a HTML, DOM, XML or something similiar structure.
Use `XPath`, and parse to the Tag and let it return the `src` `Attribute`, this will save much trouble and you can forget about regular expressions.

Example: [CLICK ME](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp)